# Developing a (Marketplace) Chrome Web Store Web App

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have trouble finding information about how to develop a Google (Marketplace) Chrome Web Store Web App.

I want to develop a simple "list info about all users in the domain, and let them add info about themselves through some web interface"-web-app.

And eventually i want to publish it in the Marketplace/Chrome Web Store.

How and where are those web apps hosted when published? How do i develop and test it before, do i use the App Engine simulator for that?

I want to be able to install the app in our domain in such a way that noone else has to "install" it.

Answer (score 0):

You should start here: https://developer.chrome.com/home/platform-pillar

About the App store: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore

Comment: Those links seem to only talk about chrome-apps. Whereas i want to develop a "marketplace" app. I dont even know what the proper name for that is:)

Comment: There are no guidelines for developing your own marketplace. You have to design it by yourself, then host it on your own server. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is the *jumping off point* you want](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).